# Excel::Writer::XLSX append text on a cell

Tags: perl

I looked at the documentation couldn;t find it so far.  I'm using "Excel::Writer::XLSX" to write text to excel.

Question is : How can I append any text on a cell.  Supposed cell A1 has "abc" already written , how can i append it with say "def" with any delimiter . Finally A1 cell should have "abc-def".

Currently its  overwritten the old data and only showing "def" .

```
File has say :  
Hostname name abc
Random Lines 
Hostname name def
Random Data 



open my $FH, '<', $filenames or die $!;
while(<$FH>)
{
            if($_ =~ /^Hostname+\s+name+\s(.*)/){
            my $hostname = $1;
            print "\nHostname : $1\n";      
                $worksheet->write(0, 0, $hostname);
            }
}
```

Now if you look at the code..when the first regex matach its write on the cell as abc ...Now when the regex match next time ...it delete abc and write def..I wanted someway to append  it...

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel::Writer::XLSX does not expose functionality to read the temporary file, while you create it. You need to save the value outside the loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hostname = '';
my $delimiter = '-';
open my $FH, '<', $filenames or die $!;
while(<$FH>)
{
    if($_ =~ /^Hostname+\s+name+\s(.*)/){
        $hostname .= $delimiter if ($hostname);
        $hostname .= $1;
        print "\nHostname : $hostname\n";      
    }
}
$worksheet->write(0, 0, $hostname);
```

To hack the internal data structure to get the temporary value [this](https://metacpan.org/source/Excel::Writer::XLSX::Worksheet#L2260) is how it says it:

```
# Write a shared string or an in-line string based on optimisation level.
if ( $self->{_optimization} == 0 ) {
    $index = $self->_get_shared_string_index( $str );
}
else {
    $index = $str;
}
$self->{_table}->{$row}->{$col} = [ $type, $index, $xf ];
```

So to read the string back, without optimisation:

```
my $value = $self->{_table}->{$row}->{$col}->[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments....  I was looking for if there is any append option in the excel write module am using. ...

Comment: Thought of letting everyone know.... Append option is not available in this module. I did sent an email to John Mcnamara who wrote the module and he confirmed.  I was already aware of the workaround  given by Bolav  ...am going to accept the solution as it will help other.   thanks